# С++. Конструктор копирования и указатели

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

```
class CList
{
public:
    struct list
    {
        char info[100];
        struct list *next;
    };
    struct list *head;

    CList(); 
    CList(const CList &obj);
    ~CList();
};
```

Собственно, как сделать конструктор копирования?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
 // Harry подсказал, что это явно похоже на список
 head = new list();
 list* current = head;
 list* forCopy = obj.head;
 while(forCopy != NULL)
 {
    current = new list();
    memcpy(current, forCopy, sizeof(list));
    forCopy = forCopy.next;
    current.next = new list();
    current = current.next;
 }
```

Comment: Плохо. Это и не поверхностное копирование - вы создаете новый узел списка, но и не глубокое - вы не идете дальше по списку. Результат получается, гм... недоделанный.

Comment: Да, согласен, не увидел сразу, что это похоже на список.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, что именно вы хотите получить. Вы можете просто скопировать указатель `head` - в таком случае это будет объект, указывающий на тот же список.

Но если вы хотите полностью скопировать весь список - то надо рекурсивно идти по цепочке, т.е. создать копию того `list`, на который указывает head, установить `head` указывающим на него, перейти к этому `list` (эк вы его неудачно назвали! `node` было бы куда лучше). В нем, если в оригинале `next` не нулевой - повторяем те же действия...

Примерно так. По сути, это и есть разница между поверхностным и глубоким копированием...

*Update* Я бы сделал примерно так - конструктор `list`:

```
struct list
{
    char info[100];
    struct list *next;

    list(const list& l)
    {
        memcpy(info,l.info,100);
        if (l.next == 0) next = 0;
        else
            next = new list(*l.next);
    }
};
```

и тогда конструктор `CList` стал бы

```
CList(const CList &obj)
{
    if (obj.head == 0) head = 0;
    else head = new list(*obj.head);
}
```

Не компилировал, просто изложил идею.

Comment: Почему-то кажется, что плоские копии обычно получаются по ошибке. Ни разу не стояла задача сделать именно плоскую копию. Только накосячить можно так.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Обычно - да, но исключения только подтверждают правило :)